# Why my React-Redux action returns "undefined"?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to get user_id from an async function. This is my action:

```js
export const loginCC = (email, password) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    async function CC_Session() {
      return ConnectyCube.createSession({
        email: email,
        password: password,
      });
    }
    try {
      const response = await CC_Session();
      const uid = response.user_id; //THIS GIVES THE USER ID WITHOUT A PROBLEM
      const token = response.token; // THIS GIVES THE DATA TOO
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_TO_CONNECTYCUBE,
        ccid: uid,
        ccToken: token,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
};
```

And this is my reducer:

```js
const initialState = {
  token: null,
  userId: null,
  ccid: null,
  ccToken: null,
  isConnected: null,
};
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_TO_CONNECTYCUBE:
      return {
        ccid: action.ccid,
        ccToken: action.ccToken,
      };
```

I can get data from async function, and dispatch it.
But when I want to access it with `getState().auth.ccid`, it returns "undefined".
How can I solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you try `action.payload.ccid` instead of `action.ccid` ? - Also your code looks like it should be `getState().ccid` instead of `getState().auth.ccid`, but I guess this is a module called `auth` with an own state, than that might be correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Tried action.payload.ccid, and it stuck. Not worked :(

Comment: Also getState().auth.ccid must be work because I get different state variables with the same code. Don't understand why it's not working.

Comment: @T.Demirer Look at the redux devtools, what actions are dispatched and what changes do they make to the state. Where do you try `getState().auth.ccid `and when? Maybe the other async function is not finished yet so you don't get the value yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. I got a Firebase login right after this action. Looks like the Firebase login action resets the state. I created another reducer called user. And dispatched the action above to that user reducer. I don't know why Firebase action resets the state, but it worked after dividing reducers.